# Error de sintaxis en el código para construir una Transformada de Fourier

Tags: python-3.7, sintaxis

estoy construyendo un código para calcular la Transformada de Fourier de un sismograma y en el código el único problema que me marca es "Sintaxis inválida" en "TFP = T_F(sis)" y no tengo idea de que pueda estar mal.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

```
import numpy as np
from obspy import read
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

def T_F(archivo):
    st = read(archivo)
    s = st[0].data
    N = len(s)
    F = np.empty(N, dtype = 'complex_')
    n = np.arange(0, N-1, 1)/N
    for k in range(0,N-1):
    F[k] = sum(s*(np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*n*k)))
    return (F)

sis = 'ARIG.HHN.sac'

#print(st[0].data)
N = len(st[0].data)
dt = st[0].stats.delta
#Para el vector de tiempo 
t = np.arange(0, N*dt, dt)
fN = 1/(2*dt)
frec = (0, fN, (int(N/2))
#Gráfica de la transformada 
TFP = T_F(sis)
plt.loglog(t,TFP)
plt.show
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo esto:

```
def T_F(archivo):
    f=open(archivo,'r')
    st=f.read()
    s=st[0].data
    N=len(s)
    F=np.empty(N, dtype='complex_')
    n=np.arange(0, N-1, 1)/N
    for k in range(0,N-1):
    F[k]=sum(s*(np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*n*k)))
    return (F)
```